# Jquery taking much time to run in mobile chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

i have a website its working fine in desktop but when i run it into mobile Browser  specially chrome. and adding books to wishlist's it takes about 1 minute to process. its working great in Firefox.

website link - [bookwise.co.in](http://bookwise.co.in)

my code is :

```
class BaseClass {
  constructor() {
    if (this.constructor === BaseClass) {
      throw new Error("Can't instantiate abstract class!");
    }
  }
  post(data, success, failure) {
    var endpoint = this.endpoint;
    showLoader();
    $.ajax({
      url: SITE_URL + endpoint,
      data: data,
      type: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'X-API-KEY': globalUser.accessToken
      },
      success: function(data) {
        hideLoader();
        if (typeof(success) == 'function') {
          success(data)
        }
      },
      error: function(err) {
        hideLoader();
        if (typeof(failure) == 'function') {
          failure(err)
        }
      }

    });
  }
  delete(data, success, failure) {
    var endpoint = this.endpoint;
    showLoader();
    $.ajax({
      url: SITE_URL + endpoint,
      data: data,
      type: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        'X-API-KEY': globalUser.accessToken
      },
      success: function(data) {
        hideLoader();
        if (typeof(success) == 'function') {
          success(data)
        }
      },
      error: function(err) {
        hideLoader();
        if (typeof(failure) == 'function') {
          failure(err)
        }
      }

    });
  }
}

class Wishlist extends BaseClass {
    constructor(endpoint) {
        super();
        this.endpoint = endpoint ? endpoint : 'wishlist';
     }
 } 
function bindWishListToggle() {
  $(".wishlist-toggle-btn").unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).parents(".similar-book-item").data("id");
    var isWishList = $(this).data("wishlist");
    var _this = this;

    var wishlist = new Wishlist();

    var successCb = function() {
      $(_this).find("img").attr("src", isWishList ? "assets/images/heartempty.png" : "assets/images/heartfull.png");
      $(_this).data("wishlist", !isWishList);
    };

    var failCB = function(data) {
      if (data.status == 401)
        $("#myModal").modal();
    }

    if (isWishList) {
      wishlist.delete({
        bookId: id
      }, successCb, failCB);
    } else {
      wishlist.post({
        bookId: id
      }, successCb, failCB);
    }
  });
}
```

above are my code i don't know why its happening only in chrome.

Comment: This question can not be answered unless you won't post the `relevant` code

Comment: @messerbill i have added script

Comment: Is that the only jQuery running on your website? (Where's the `WishList` constructor?)

Comment: @Seth i have add all my scripts

Comment: You added `BaseClass`, what about `WishList`? You need to post all applicable code. Something could be processing in the `WishList` class' constructor that's causing this behavior. Always post any associated code (with sensitive information redacted)

Comment: @Seth added Wishlist.